# IIS Sub domains pointing to the same folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, directory, subdomain

I am developing a multi-tenant application in ASP.Net running on IIS 7.5

I want to provide different sub-domains to each of the tenants (customers). While the sub-domains are different, they all need to point to the same deployment folder. Application identifies the tenant based on the request URL.

Will there be a problem if there are thousands (tens of thousand!) sub-domains pointing to the same folder?

Also, how does one programmatically create sub-domains in IIS?

Thanks,

Vikram

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't manage the customers with a single sub domain?

Comment: Primarily non-technical, but important for the customers. The customers will like to have their own branding right from the landing page. We don't want to have our own branding anywhere on the page (may be except the "Powered By" line in the footer).

Comment: By subdomains do you mean xxx.mysite.com yyy.mysite.com? Or mysite.com/xxx mysite.com/yyy? In the first case every time you add a subdomain you should change the dns. configuration? Is it that what you want?

Comment: I mean xxx.mysite.com yyy.mysite.com. I can specify a wild card (*.mysite.com) in the A records, so that won't be much trouble. The problem is on IIS side, where IIS will need to know which subdomain maps to what directory.